# Laravel 5.7 optimize data for select input

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent

I have a table called Places(id, name, timestamps) where I have around 4k rows.
I need to send all of them to my create.blade.php select input where it will show their names and send my back id. It looks like this

```
<select name="place_id" class="form-control">
  @foreach($palces as $place)
    <option value="{{ $place->id }}">{{ $place->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

The problem is it take a lot of time to load it especially when you click to expand select.
This is in my controller

```
$places = Place::all()->sortBy('name');
```

Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: better to used search functionality  it will reduce your load time

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? In rendering the page (which makes it a backend problem) or in the browser itself?

Comment: It takes a lot of time to load all data to my select input, and app then looks like it's not optimized at all.

Comment: Are you sure you need 4k rows on page? It is practical to have at most 50-100 but even less data on page with applied pagination. For representing (searching over) lot of data it is also good to use datatables package with AJAX support.

Comment: @Tpojka well I need it, I need all places from my country when building a profile for user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DB facade instead of Eloquent, you could install [DebugBar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and see if it is faster in the queries section.

Comment: have you tried to pluck() only necessary fields (id, name) of the place instead of returning all the row?

Comment: Also try to see if is the act of ordering the time consuming operation.